# Accessing command line (cmd) from RStudio

Tags: r

In my work under R I need to make the call to another software (ANSYS)
For that I am looking for a command under R which allows access to the command line windows (cmd).
For example under matlab the character (!) Allows to do it
thank you

Comment: Have you tried `system()` or `system2()`? It will invoke os command and works fine on ubuntu. Not sure whether it also works well on Windows.

Comment: thank, it's working but for the continuity of my code R, I use the results of of the linen executed by (cmd), the problem is that Rstudion passes To the next line without waiting for the end of the execution of the command by (cmd)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `system`, `system2`, or `shell` on Windows.

If ANSYS is not in your path then you will have to call it directly:

`system("/path/to/ansys140.exe ansys_script.ans")`

Comment: thank, it's working but for the continuity of my code R, I use the results of of the linen executed by (cmd), the problem is that Rstudion passes To the next line without waiting for the end of the execution of the command by (cmd)

Answer (score 1):

The only *portable* functions are `system()` and `system2()`. All relevant information is as usual in the behind `help("system")`.  R will then execute whatever command you give it *provided it is in the `$PATH`*.

In case you wanted to also work interactively, you can use a more recent daily build of RStudio, you will get a completely full-feature *terminal tab* as well.  So just upgrade to a [daily build](https://dailies.rstudio.com/).

Comment: thank, it's working but for the continuity of my code R, I use the results of of the linen executed by (cmd), the problem is that Rstudion passes To the next line without waiting for the end of the execution of the command by (cmd)

Answer (score 0):

thank you
Yes, it is this command that I seek but once I place my command in it, an error is displayed and indicates that R does not accept the santax

the command is
 system(paste('"C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\v150\ANSYS\bin\winx64\ansys150.exe"  -p ane3fl -dir "C:\Users\hamdani\Documents" -j "hamid" -s read -l en-us -b -i "C:\Users\hamdani\Documents\Plane Stress Bracket.txt" -o "C:\Users\hamdani\Documents\fichier.out"'), wait = FALSE)

the error is
Error: '\P' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'"C:\P"

When I place the command directly in the System Command, it works very well

Comment: Backslash is an escape character in R. So you need to type two to get one to go to the shell.

Comment: P.S. this would have perhaps been better as an edit or new question